# Sorting structs in C with qsort

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I have a struct in C like this:

```
typedef struct proces {
    char ime[60];
    char pid[60];
    char ppid[60];
    char stanje;
    int stdat;
    char niti[60];
    char poraba[60];
} proces ;
```

I create about 100 of them and put them into an array

```
proces** procesi = malloc(sizeof(proces));
int x;
for(x=0; x<st; x++){
    procesi[x] = (struct proces*)malloc(sizeof(proces));
}
```

Now I would like to sort them with qsort. But the qsort sorts it wrong.
The function looks like this:

```
int compar_ppid(const void *v1, const void *v2){
   const proces *p1 = (proces*)v1;
   const proces *p2 = (proces*)v2;
   return(strcmp(p1->ppid, p2->ppid));
}
```

I checked the values that the compar_ppid is comparing and they seem to be something like �#d, when they should be numbers.

I guess I'm accessing the pointer and not the value, but I cant figure out what to change to get the right values.

Qsort call:

```
qsort(procesi, st, sizeof(proces*), compar_name);
```

Comment: `proces** procesi = malloc(sizeof(proces));`--->`proces** procesi = malloc(st*sizeof(proces*));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you sort contains pointers to `process`, so your compare function should look like:

```
int compar_ppid(const void * v1, const void * v2)
{
    process *const*p1 = v1, *const*p2 = v2;
    return strcmp((*p1)->ppid, (*p2)->ppid);
}
```

and as  BLUEPIXY points out the allocation of the array is not using the pointer size, but the struct size.

Comment: It works now, but I'm getting a warning:  warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]

Comment: My bad. Fixed the example. I hardly ever use `const` myself, highly overrated.